# Spring Boot - interfaces and some functions implement

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a question about SpringBoot.

I have an interface, two implementations, I want to implement some functions implementation A, some functions implementation B. How can make it? Service interface and implementations like so:

ServiceInterface.java

```
public interface ServiceInterface{

void functionA();
void functionB();
void functionC();
}
```

ServiceImp1.java

```
public class ServiceImp1 implements ServiceInterface{

@Override
public void functionA(){

 //function A

}

@Override
public void functionB(){

 //function B

}}
```

ServiceImp2.java

```
public class ServiceImp2 implements ServiceInterface{

@Override
public void functionC(){

 //function C

}}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seems related to Spring at all until you maye two service implementing the same interface and @Qualifier to discriminate them during injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 supports having a default implementation for interfaces so you could do something like

```
public interface ServiceInterface {

    default void functionA() {
    }
    
    default void functionB() {
    }
    
    default void functionC() {
    }
}
```

to provide an empty implementation on default (although I would question the decision to have a common interface if methods are not required to be implemented at all).